Incompatibility node driver requirements and mongoDB maximum wire version
I am updating my ancient node application to the latest npm packages, and things are moving. The heart of my application is a link to a mongoDB instance, which holds everything together. And now I am getting this error:

MongoServerSelectionError: Server at 127.0.0.1:27017 reports maximum wire version 5, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6)

This is baffling. I am operating node v20.17.0. I have mongo-connect 5.1.0. I have upgraded references to MongoStore etc to accord with the changes in mongoDB.  "mongod --version" tells me I have "db version v6.0.17". I can connect to the database on port 27017 using Robo 3T.
Why am I getting these errors? I do not want to try to rollback to a previous node or mongoDB.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "tc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 startOrReload pm2.json",
    "prod": "pm2 startOrReload pm2.json --env production",
    "logs": "pm2 logs",
    "test": "node --use_strict $(npm bin)/jasmine"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "async": "^3.2.6",
    "base64url": "^3.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "bson": "^6.8.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.65.17",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jsdom": "^24.1.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
    "libxmljs": "^1.0.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongo-connect": "^0.0.6",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^2.1.5",
    "openseadragon": "^5.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.4",
    "promise-defer": "^1.0.0",
    "require-in-the-middle": "^7.4.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "sort-array": "^4.1.5",
    "urijs": "^1.19.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "jasmine": "^5.2.0",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.94.0"
  }
}

And here is my webpack.js:
var _ = require('lodash')
  , webpack = require('webpack')
  , ResolverPlugin = webpack.ResolverPlugin
  , ProvidePlugin = webpack.ProvidePlugin
  , IgnorePlugin = webpack.IgnorePlugin
//  , ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
  , path = require('path')
  , clientRoot = path.resolve(__dirname)
  , bowerRoot = path.resolve(clientRoot, '..', 'bower_components')
  , nodeRoot = path.resolve(clientRoot, '..', 'node_modules')
  , devtool = 'eval-source-map'
  , debug = true
;

switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'production':
    devtool = '#source-map';
    debug = false;
    break;
  case 'development':
    devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    debug = true;
    break;
}

var config = {
  context: clientRoot,
  entry: {
    app: path.join(clientRoot, 'app/boot.js'),
    t: path.join(clientRoot, 'app/t.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(clientRoot, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate(info) {
     return `file:///${info.absoluteResourcePath.replace(/\\/g, '/')}`;
   },
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    rxjs: 'Rx',
    lodash: '_',
    bson: 'bson',
    'codemirror/lib/codemirror': 'CodeMirror',
    'codemirror/mode/xml/xml': false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.png(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=image/jpg&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.jpg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=image/jpg&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/font-woff&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/font-woff&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/octet-stream&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&prefix=dist/"
      }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: "url?limit=1000&minetype=image/svg+xml&prefix=dist/"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use:["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        //loader: 'style!css'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
    //          javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            }, 
          },
        ],
      },
    ], /*,
    noParse: [
    ] */
  },
  resolve: {
 /*   root: [clientRoot], */
    modules: [clientRoot, 'web_modules', 'node_modules', 'bower_components', ],
    fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "path": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "stream": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "crypto-browserify": false, //if you want to use this module also don't forget npm i crypto-browserify 
      },
    alias: {
      bower: bowerRoot,
      node: nodeRoot,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true
    }),
/*    new ResolverPlugin(new ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin(
      'bower.json', ['main']
    )), 
     new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("package.json", ["main"])
    ), */
   // prevent webpack accident include server security information
//    new IgnorePlugin(new RegExp('config\/production.*')),
//    new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css"),
/*    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
      chunks: ['app'],
      minChunks: function(module, count) {
        return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(clientRoot) === -1;
      }
    }), */

  ],
  devtool: devtool,
};

var compiler = webpack(config);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  compiler.watch({
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
  }, handleError);
} else {
 compiler.watch({
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
  }, handleError);
  //compiler.run(handleError);
}

function handleError(err, stats) {
  console.log(stats.toString({
    colors: true,
    cached: false,
  }));
}

I am working on a mac with Sonoma 14.6.1. Help.. (yes, several other people have hit this error, but none I think with the combination of mongoDB and node versions I have).
Addendum: I think the problem maybe that the mongo database I have is ancient. Do I need to upgrade the database itself, as well as the mongoDB instance and node? Checking that now..
Updating: after many problems, I finally ended up with upgrading MongoDB with an empty database, up to MongoDB community 7.0. I had a dump of the original database, so I restored that, and now everything is working. So anyone else who hits this problem: dump your database (very easy in mongo), run the latest mongodb with an empty database, and then use mongo restore to bring back your data.

maximum wire version 5 - is less than server 3.6, so this is '"db version v6.0.17"' unlikely possible. I assume the connection string to db that throws that error doesn't point to the mongod server which you called getting version for later. So something is messed up

As a result of repeated uninstall/reinstalls of mongoDB I now do not have a working version of mongoDB: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78910560/mongodb-will-not-run-on-macos. I'll return to this issue when I get mongoDB running again.

if your current question is unrelated to compatibility question here, then close this SO
